# select rows that contain a character but does not contain another in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case, nsregularexpression

from the dataframe below

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("ap(pl)e", "or(a)ng%e", "pe%ar", "bl(u%)e", "red"),
                 col2 = c(1,3,5,4,8))
df
       col1 col2
1   ap(pl)e    1
2 or(a)ng%e    3
3     pe%ar    5
4   bl(u%)e    4
5       red    8
```

I want to filter rows whose values in col1 contains ( but %.

```
     col1 col2
1 ap(pl)e    1
2   pe%ar    5
3     red    8
```

So I am using case_when along with gprel. this is going to be part of the dplyr pipes.

```
#works
df %>%
    mutate(result = case_when((grepl("p", .[[1]]) & !grepl("r", .[[1]])) ~"Yes",
#does not work                                      TRUE~"No"))
df %>%
    mutate(result = case_when((grepl("(", .[[1]]) & !grepl("%", .[[1]])) ~"Yes",
                                      TRUE~"No"))
```

this does not work for % and (. is there any trick to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering why your code did not work then add slashes in front of '('.

```
df %>%
  mutate(result = case_when((grepl("\\(", .[[1]]) & !grepl("%", .[[1]])) ~"Yes",TRUE~"No"))
```

Output:

```
       col1 col2 result
1   ap(pl)e    1    Yes
2 or(a)ng%e    3     No
3     pe%ar    5     No
4   bl(u%)e    4     No
5       red    8     No
```

Comment: why !grepl("%", .[[1]]) is not working. I m actually going to select those rows with ( and without %. Thank you for the \\ trick !

Answer (score 2):

We could match the pattern of `(` followed by any characters (`.*`) and `%` in `str_detect`, return TRUE/FALSE for the negated cases (`negate = TRUE`) to `filter` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(col1, "\\(.*%", negate = TRUE))
```

-output

```
      col1 col2
1 ap(pl)e    1
2   pe%ar    5
3     red    8
```

---

If it needs to be a column

```
df %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(str_detect(col1, "\\(.*%", 
     negate = TRUE) ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"))
       col1 col2 result
1   ap(pl)e    1    Yes
2 or(a)ng%e    3     No
3     pe%ar    5    Yes
4   bl(u%)e    4     No
5       red    8    Yes
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df, seq_along(col1) %in% grep("\\(.*%", col1, invert = TRUE))
      col1 col2
1 ap(pl)e    1
3   pe%ar    5
5     red    8
```

Comment: ! Thank you very neat and pretty. However I need to get the out using case_when() because of my set up in my actual code.

Comment: @Mathica you can just take the code in `mutate` i.e. `df %>% mutate(result = case_when(str_detect(col1, "\\(.*%", negate = TRUE) ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"))`

Comment: @Mathica What is your expected output

Comment: my desired output is exactly what you got from the filter() approach. but I need it with case_when.

Comment: @Mathica Then, what about the updated cod3

Comment: this one? df %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(str_detect(col1, "\\(.*%", 
     negate = TRUE) ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"))--- This does not give the desired output unfortunately

Comment: @Mathica What is your desired output?  You want `Yes` to have the values remaining or the ones leaving

Comment: I assume I will have to use both case_when and filter then. no other way around. but it was very helpful comparing your approaches! Thank you!

Comment: @Mathica Please note that if you want Yes to be reverse, either switch the statements or remove the `negate = TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy a regex using `grepl`.

```
df[!grepl('\\(.*%', df$col1, perl=TRUE), ]
#      col1 col2
# 1 ap(pl)e    1
# 3   pe%ar    5
# 5     red    8
```